# Accessing another app's files

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, ionic-framework

Background information: I am using Ionic framework to make a mobile application that can run on both ios and android.

Fore explanation purpose, I want to use App A(I am making this app) to the music files in App B(ex. Spotify,music player). So users can use my App A to select the App B, and I will import all the music files to my App A. Then the user can select which music to play. All process are done with App A.

Is there a plugin that can do this? Or is there a pre-existing command to do this. I am fairly new to app development. I know this is achievable, but how is it usually accomplished.

Hopefully, my description is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Content Providers`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) can help you, refer this [blog post](http://codetheory.in/android-sharing-application-data-with-content-provider-and-content-resolver/)

And also, this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/building-content-sharing.html) will give you all about sharing data between apps.